# Resource sharing between war files

Tags: spring, web, resources, war

We've multiple wars being deployed on one server.
The CSS, JS, images, ... are mostly common for all war files.
What is the best way to serve these resources?
Options I've found so far:

- Use Maven Overlay plugin (This causes us to loose flexibility of hot-swapping resources in our IDE)
- Create a common jar to package in your war (needs Servlet 3.0 api if I'm correct)
- Create a war file that contains only resources and that can be deployed on the server as well

Answer (score 0):

If you have may users, then a content delivery network would be an appropriate way to deliver the static files.